# send email from several textboxs in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

at the moment i'm using a  string[] to get all the emails from textboxs,
and the sending them one at time.

someone have a better idea for getting the the text and sending it ?

Comment: Please provide more information. Post the code you have written so far. That will be easy for everyone to better understand your problem and provide accurate solutions.

Comment: @tfman, its not clear if your textboxes (or string[]) indicates addresses or email bodies - please clarify - if you want to send same email to *given* multiple recipients or *given* multiple emails to one/more fixed recipients.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the controls on your page.  Of the control's type is textbox, add the text to your string[].

Comment: thanks for the idea , now the code looks nicer (used cast object instead of string[] ).